# Understanding R Shiny modules: Error in shiny::NS(id) : argument "id" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny, module

I am trying to understand the concept of shiny modules. I am attempting to modularize this very simple `shinydashboard` app:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(uiOutput("box"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$box <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      subtitle = "Hi",
      value = 2
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

which works as desired.

However, when modularizing I keep getting the following mistake:
`Error in shiny::NS(id) : argument "id" is missing, with no default`.

```
#### Modules ####
costumizedValueBox <- function(id) {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("box"))
}

costumizedValueBoxServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$box <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
          subtitle = "Hi",
          value = 2
        )
      })
    }
  )
}

#### App ####
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(costumizedValueBox())
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  costumizedValueBoxServer()
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried different modifications of the modularized code, none of which worked, e. g. changing the output (to `textOutput`) or the general setup. The error message suggests a problem with the `NS` function but I am not able to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Pass a string - the same string - as the argument to both your module ui and module server function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what @Limey describes in the comments: To learn in detail see here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

```
library(shiny)

#### Modules ####
costumizedValueBox <- function(id, label = "ValueBox_custom") {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("box"))
}

costumizedValueBoxServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$box <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
          subtitle = "Hi",
          value = 2
        )
      })
    }
  )
}

#### App ####
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(costumizedValueBox("ValueBox_custom1"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  costumizedValueBoxServer("ValueBox_custom1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modules (i.e., costumizedValueBoxServer and costumizedValueBox) are functions with a required argument.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(costumizedValueBox("my_id")) # pass in an ID
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  costumizedValueBoxServer("my_id") # pass in the same ID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just when you call your module, make sure to assign an id for it in quotes. Job well done, I've been learning about this too. Make sure your id matches your module calls in both server and UI sections of your app.
Here is a youtube link, you've probably already seen, but the timestamp shows what I am talking about.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOYaHsPXLvs

````
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(costumizedValueBox("VBox_id_1")) # pass in an ID
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  costumizedValueBoxServer("VBox_id_1") # pass in the same ID
}```
````